# HELP - Corrupted items in a List

Tags: list

I currently have a list with over 32,000 items.  The other day, Friday the 13th one of the SAN Drives went down and the Content Database that holds this list had corruption.  So to make a long story even longer I have to recover everything that was created on the 12 & 13 and copy those items into the production list.  I have to have the Created, Created By, Modified and Modified By data when I copy.
I have a tool that does that, Metalogix.  But the list will not render in Metalogix because some of the old data is corrupted.  So my question is, How  in the heck to I delete all of the data in the list expect for the 12 & 13.  I have tried doing it in Data Sheet mode but it will not delete it.  Is there a programmatic way, an Admin command, how can I get this done.

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt to connect to the list in Microsoft Access. This may let you access the old records to delete them (can even write basic SQL against the list that way).

Comment: Hi, thanks for much for your comment, but I tried that and it will not connect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to recommend this, but if you have no other option you could try:

- Attach a copy of the corrupted content database to a SQL server in a test farm
- Open SQL management studio
- DELETE FROM [dbo].[AllUserData]
   WHERE tp_ListId = 'Your List Guid'
   AND NOT tp_modified BETWEEN '2012-07-12' AND '2012-07-14'
- Attach database to webapp in test farm
- See if Metalogix will read the list